# Any tool which generate C++ code against a design

Tags: c++, uml, class-design

I have a class diagram , I want that to draw it in some tool which can generate native C++ out of it , I wish to have design first approach to test the various data structures I am designing for my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of tools can make C++ code out of UML diagrams. Try [Software Ideas Modeller](http://www.softwareideas.net/) for example, it's a great UML tool, and it's free for non-commercial use.

Also, [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools#Features) has a list of UML tools. You can sort them by "languages generated" column to check what they do support and chose the one that you will like.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try  [**UMLET**](http://www.umlet.com) for your work.

You can seach mofre on google by typing

**related:www.softwareideas.net**

**related:www.umlet.com**

From [Tricky Hacker](http://www.trickyhacker.com)

Comment: Excerpt from UMLET site's FAQ section "Can I create code from UMLet's uxf-files?
UMLet does not provide means to create code from the model, or vice-versa. However, UMLet's uxf file format is a very simple XML format; you can easily parse it with, eg, XSLT, to process the model.
UMLet is aimed at fast UML sketching---we do not plan to support code creation or round-trip engineering in the future."