# How to generate C++ Code from UML Diagrams in VIsual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I've drawn UML Class Diagrams in Visual Studio, but when I generate code and select class template, it generates C# codes, how can I generate C++ Codes and put them right in my project directory? Because my code project and modeling project are under the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the question: [Any tool which generate C++ code against a design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574143/any-tool-which-generate-c-code-against-a-design), try and investigate software packages that help you achieve your code without Visual Studio.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools

Comment: well, I asked for VSC solution. is there any? VSC seems to be a total solution...

Comment: Perhaps this might help - http://kemal.co/index.php/2012/08/creating-classes-from-uml-diagrams-in-visual-studio-2012/